# Display employee name,total salary of each employee(total salary=salary+commission)

Tags: sql

Display employee name, total salary of each employee.

**Conditions:**

- if commission is `not NULL` then `total salary=(salary + commission)`
- else `total salary = salary`;

Here is my table:

Table name: `myemp`

Columns:

```
empno [Primary key], name, salary, commission, deptno

create table myemp
( 
     empno number primary key,
     name varchar2(20),
     salary number,
     commission number,
     deptno number
);
```

Query:

```
select
    name, salary, commission,
    (salary + ((salary*commission) / 100)) as "total_salary" 
from myemp;
```

This query give incorrect result.

When commission is `NULL`, then `total_salary = 0`. But it should be `total_salay=salary`;

How to fix this?

Comment: What is the result you get, what is the result you expected? can you add an example for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

```
(salary + ((salary*coalesce(commission,0) / 100))) as "total_salary"
```

Answer (score 1):

My table like below:
SQL> select * from emp;

```
 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
```

---

```
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10
```

14 rows selected.

My result table while i have null value in comm column is:

SQL> select empno,ename,sal,comm,(sal+nvl(comm,0)) as "Total_sal" from emp;

```
 EMPNO ENAME             SAL       COMM  Total_sal
```

---

```
  7369 SMITH             800                   800
  7499 ALLEN            1600        300       1900
  7521 WARD             1250        500       1750
  7566 JONES            2975                  2975
  7654 MARTIN           1250       1400       2650
  7698 BLAKE            2850                  2850
  7782 CLARK            2450                  2450
  7788 SCOTT            3000                  3000
  7839 KING             5000                  5000
  7844 TURNER           1500          0       1500
  7876 ADAMS            1100                  1100
  7900 JAMES             950                   950
  7902 FORD             3000                  3000
  7934 MILLER           1300                  1300
```

14 rows selected.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nvl function to check availability of salary and commission, if salary and commission is not null then both are summed up, if salary or commission is null then it will take 0 instead of null, if both are null then it will take 0 as total salary so this way you can calculate salary + commission by  using nvl function (nvl function is only available in oracle).

```
    select name,salary,commission,nvl(salary,0)+nvl(commission,0) as Total_salary from myemp;
```

for mysql and sql server you may use IFNULL function.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
 select
    name, salary, commission,
    (salary + coalesce(((salary * commission) / 100), 0)) "total_salary" 
 from myemp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the salary + the commission, if there is one. The issue is not how to conditionally add the commission, but rather how much to add onto the salary. You know that the result will be at least the employees initial salary, so if the commission did not exist then just add 0 as the commission.

```
Select name, (salary + IsNull(commission, 0)) as total_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

select salary*months as totalearing,count(*) from Employee  group by totalearing order by totalearing desc limit 1;

created by 
Rahul Panwar

Comment: We define an employee's total earnings to be their monthly  worked, and the maximum total earnings to be the maximum total earnings for any employee in the Employee table. Write a query to find the maximum total earnings for all employees as well as the total number of employees who have maximum total earnings. Then print these values as  space-separated integers.

Comment: select salary*months as totalearing,count() from Employee group by totalearing order by totalearing desc limit 1;